# Jira Web Service issue comment add-delete-edit

Tags: jira

How to use WebService, add-edit-delete issue comment?

```
using (jiraext.JiraSoapServiceService service = new jiraext.JiraSoapServiceService())
       {
           string auth = service.login("", "");
           jiraext.RemoteIssue[] issues = service.getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit(auth, "10802", 1, 1000);
           while (issues.Length > 0)
           {
               foreach (jiraext.RemoteIssue thisissue in issues)
                      **????????????????**
            }       
           }
       }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved;

```
     using (jiraext.JiraSoapServiceService service = new jiraext.JiraSoapServiceService())
        {
            string auth = service.login("userName", "Pwd");
            jiraext.RemoteIssue[] issues = service.getIssuesFromFilterWithLimit(auth, "10802", 1, 1000);
            while (issues.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (jiraext.RemoteIssue thisissue in issues)
                    try
                    {

                      int msgLenght = service.getComments(auth, thisissue.key).Length-1; //last comment
                      string comm = service.getComments(auth, thisissue.key)[msgLenght].body.ToString(); //last comment body
                      comm = comm + "__!"; // last comment body change 
                      long msgID = Convert.ToInt64(service.getComments(auth, thisissue.key)[msgLenght].id.ToString()); //last comment ID
                      jiraext.RemoteComment comment = service.getComment(auth, msgID);
                      comment.body = comm;
                      service.editComment(auth, comment);


                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { }

            }
        }
```